# When following the official instructions to install and configure MariaDB with a new ejabberd 23.4 installation the mysql connections all fail

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ejabberd

The below steps were completed:
New install of ejabberd 23.4 - operating normally with successful access to the admin portal and via an XMPP client.

Followed the Process One tutorial:
[Install and configure MariaDB with ejabberd](https://www.process-one.net/blog/install-and-configure-mariadb-with-ejabberd/)

ejabberd database and user setup and checked - access is correct.
data tables contain all the data exported from mnesia and inserted into mysql
MariaDB server operating correctly (it is used by another application with no issues) and can be accessed with the ejabberd user separately.

However, I cannot get any operation with mysql:

Extracts from ejabberd.log (log level debug):

```
2023-07-13 12:15:39.491507+02:00 [info] <0.174.0>@ejabberd_config:load/1:82 Loading configuration from /opt/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml
2023-07-13 12:15:39.512762+02:00 [notice] <0.174.0>@ejabberd_logger:set/1:374 Changing loglevel from 'info' to 'debug'
2023-07-13 12:15:39.711190+02:00 [debug] <0.376.0>@supervisor_bridge:report_progress/4:139 PROGRESS REPORT:
    supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
    started: [{pid,<0.377.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]
```

I noticed there were several entries regarding mnesia (I'm not sure if this is normal), with the last mnesia entries being this:

```
2023-07-13 12:15:40.068501+02:00 [debug] <0.44.0>@application_controller:info_started/2:2107 PROGRESS REPORT:
    application: mnesia
    started_at: ejabberd@localhost
    2023-07-13 12:15:40.068640+02:00 [debug] <0.379.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:init/0:79 Waiting for Mnesia tables synchronization...
    2023-07-13 12:15:40.091356+02:00 [debug] <0.379.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:read_schema_file/0:243 No custom Mnesia schema file found at /opt/ejabberd/database/ejabberd@localhost/ejabberd.schema
```

after this all other modules appear to load correctly with several sections for sql similar to this:

```
2023-07-13 12:15:40.427290+02:00 [debug] <0.643.0>@supervisor:report_progress/2:1557 PROGRESS REPORT:
    supervisor: {local,'ejabberd_sql_sup_conciel.ltd'}
    started: [{pid,<0.644.0>},
              {id,1},
              {mfargs,{ejabberd_sql,start_link,[<<"conciel.ltd">>,1]}},
              {restart_type,transient},
              {significant,false},
              {shutdown,2000},
              {child_type,worker}]
```

but then immediately after this I get a stream of errors all similar to:

```
2023-07-13 12:15:40.432394+02:00 [warning] <0.645.0>@ejabberd_sql:handle_reconnect/2:479 mysql connection failed:

** Reason: normal

** Retry after: 5 seconds
```

I have these lines in the ejabberd.yml

Just after host and loglevel entries:

```
default_db: sql
```

and at the end of the file:

```
############## DATABASE CONFIGS ###########################
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "password"
sql_port: 3306
auth_method: sql
```

Web portal and XMPP clients do not connect, and the mariadb log entries for this are all like this:

```
2023-07-13 11:24:57 677 [Warning] Aborted connection 677 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '::1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as I am at a stalemate in diagnosing further.

Thanks!